# Не могу найти ошибку  в АСМ модуле для С

Tags: c, ассемблер

Пишу модуль для с-шной программы на nasm - сортировка пузырьком.
Программы почему-то вылетает при исполнении. Целые сутки пытался понять причину - не вышло.
Пробовал разные реализации этого когда - бесполезно.
NASM ошибок не выдает, а модуль при исполнении вылетает.

### Модуль АСМ:

```
global _bubblesort_asm
section .text

_bubblesort_asm:
    mov ebx, [esp+4] ; EBX = *m
    mov esi, [esp+8] ; ESI = size
    dec esi ; ESI = size-1 = I
    loop_i:
        xor edi, edi ; J = 0
        loop_j:
            mov ecx, [ebx+edi*4] ; ecx = value of m[J]
            mov edx, [ebx+edi*4+4] ; edx = value of m[j+1]
            cmp edx, ecx ; if(m[j] <= m[j+1])  goto skip
            jns skip
                mov [ebx+edi*4], edx ; mov value m[j+1] to m[j] adress
                mov [ebx+edi*4+4], ecx ; mov value m[j] to m[j+1] adress
            skip:
        inc edi ; j++
        cmp edi, esi ; if(j!=i) goto loop_j
        jnz loop_j
    dec esi ; I--
    cmp esi, 0 ; if(i>=0) goto loop_i
    jns loop_i
retn
;    for(i=size-1; i>=0; i--)
;        for(j=0; j<i; j++)
;            if(m[j] > m[j+1])
;                {temp = m[j]; m[j] = m[j+1]; m[j+1] = temp;}
```

### main.c:

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i,size=100,m[size];
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        m[i]=rand()%100;
    }

    bubblesort_asm(m,size);

    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",m[i]);
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: А пройтись под отладчиком не пробовали?

Comment: @kuler94, судя по всему, что-то не так с условием выхода из внешнего цикла - цикл не останавливается когда нужно, поэтому в один "прекрасный" момент во внутреннем цикле происходит запись за пределы разрешенной для записи памяти.

Comment: @insolor
Спасибо большое!
Так и есть.

Comment: @kuler94, как исправили-то?

Comment: cmp esi, 0 

Исправил на 1.

Comment: @kuler94, с адресацией вроде бы все нормально.

Для себя открыл использование js :) Я бы вместо него использовал jge, как-то для меня более интуитивно (*g*rater or *e*qual - больше или равно), чем проверка наличия знака. Посмотрел в умной книжке, в jge переход происходит, когда флаги знака и переполнения равны, ну а js понятное дело когда установлен флаг знака. В данной программе работает и тот и другой вариант. Разницу с в работе js и jge так сходу не пойму. Надо эту тему проработать, раз уж обнаружились пробелы в знаниях.

Comment: а попробуйте сервис http://gcc.godbolt.org/ - напишите на с минимальную реализацию сортировки, получите ассемблерный код (там много параметров, можно получить достаточно читаемое). Убедитесь, что оно работает как нужно, а потом начинайте "ручную оптимизацию".

Comment: @insolor
Используя jns у меня была такая логика:
esi каждую итерацию уменьшается, условие цикла >=0, следовательно, однажды флаг sf должен подняться. 
Хотя сейчас понял, что cmp был лишним, флаг бы и так установился, когда esi=-1.
А вот почему выходил за пределы изначально - не понял до сих пор.

Comment: @kuler94, проверки всех флагов, выставляемых в результате исполнения команд, работают с одной и той же скоростью.

Comment: @avp возможно, но jge ведь не является флагом сам по себе, а лишь зависит от двух других, как сказал @insolor.

Comment: @KoVadim, все бы хорошо, да только синтаксис ассемблера [s]не торт[/s] непривычный :)

**Добавлено.** Кнопку 'Intel syntax' я конечно же не заметил. Правда у меня она почему-то не работает.

Comment: ну так можно на интел переключить. Всех то делов (правда не у всех компиляторов).

Answer (score 4):

Скомпилировал сишную сортировку с помощью mingw gcc с оптимизацей -O2, дизассемблировал, получилось вот что:

```
.text:004013C5                 mov     edx, [ebp+m]
.text:004013C8                 mov     esi, [ebp+size]
.text:004013CB                 dec     esi
.text:004013CC                 js      short loc_4013F5
.text:004013CE                 db      66h ; выравнивание
.text:004013CE                 nop         ; выравнивание
.text:004013D0
.text:004013D0 loc_4013D0:                             ; CODE XREF: bubblesort+33j
.text:004013D0                 test    esi, esi
.text:004013D2                 jle     short loc_4013EF
.text:004013D4                 xor     eax, eax
.text:004013D6                 db      66h ; выравнивание
.text:004013D6                 nop         ; выравнивание
.text:004013D8
.text:004013D8 loc_4013D8:                             ; CODE XREF: bubblesort+2Dj
.text:004013D8                 mov     ecx, [edx+eax*4]
.text:004013DB                 mov     ebx, [edx+eax*4+4]
.text:004013DF                 cmp     ecx, ebx
.text:004013E1                 jle     short loc_4013EA
.text:004013E3                 mov     [edx+eax*4], ebx
.text:004013E6                 mov     [edx+eax*4+4], ecx
.text:004013EA
.text:004013EA loc_4013EA:                             ; CODE XREF: bubblesort+21j
.text:004013EA                 inc     eax
.text:004013EB                 cmp     eax, esi
.text:004013ED                 jnz     short loc_4013D8
.text:004013EF
.text:004013EF loc_4013EF:                             ; CODE XREF: bubblesort+12j
.text:004013EF                 dec     esi
.text:004013F0                 cmp     esi, -1
.text:004013F3                 jnz     short loc_4013D0
.text:004013F5
.text:004013F5 loc_4013F5:                             ; CODE XREF: bubblesort+Cj
```

Код почти идентичен тому что в вопросе, отличается некоторыми деталями, плюс gcc добавил выравнивание (66h - это префикс-модификатор размера операнда, перед nop он никаких функций не выполняет).

---

**Дополнение про различие js и jl.**

По сути cmp - это вычитание, не сохраняющее результат, но выставляющее флаги. Если сравнивать небольшие по модулю числа, то разницы в результатах не будет. Но если сравнивать числа, при вычитании дающие результат по модулю больший половины размерности переменной (регистра), то sf будет иметь не то значение, которое могло бы быть при сравнении меньших по модулю чисел.

На примере величин в пределах байта. Сравним -10 и 10 внутри байтовых регистров:

```
mov al, -10
mov cl, 10
cmp al, cl
; результат вычитания -20, флаг SF установлен
; и по js и по jl переход произойдет
```

Теперь на примере чисел -100 и 100:

```
mov al, -100
mov cl, 100
cmp al, cl
; результат вычитания "на бумаге" -200
; но в пределах байта это уже не -200, а 56, флаг знака сброшен,
; поэтому по js переход не произойдет.
; Зато выставлен флаг переполнения - OF
; По jl, которое проверяет и SF, и OF, переход произойдет.
```

**Дополнение 2.** Под половиной разрядности я имею в виду вот что: к примеру в байтовом регистре могут храниться знаковые числа от -128 до +127. В вордовом - от -2^15 до +2^15-1, в двордовом - от -2^31 до +2^31-1. Соответственно, если результат вычитания выходит за эти границы, то знак результата вычитания оказывается неверным (да и сам результат будет неверным, но в случае cmp он нас не интересует) и выставляется флаг переполнения. Поэтому чтобы определить, что одно число больше чем другое, нужно учитывать и флаг знака, и флаг переполнения, что и делают команды переходов jl (jnge), jnl (jge), jg (jnle), jng (jle).

По поводу вылета при условии выхода из внешнего цикла cmp esi, 0 ; jns loop_i. Последний виток внешний цикл должен выполнить при esi==0. Тогда во внутреннем цикле произойдет вот что:

1. edi обнулится
2. при необходимости выполнится операция перестановки соседних элементов массива
3. edi увеличится на 1
4. произойдет сравнение edi (1) с esi (0)
5. так как они не равны (edi уже больше чем esi), то выход из цикла **не произойдет**
6. далее edi будет увеличиваться и увеличиваться, пока не дойдет до конца доступного для записи участка памяти.

Если заменить cmp esi,0 на cmp esi,1, то последний виток внешний цикл выполнит при esi==1, и внутренний цикл завершится, выполнив одну итерацию. Но тут все равно возникают проблемы, если массив состоит из одного элемента или вообще пуст, тогда esi уже при проверке условия выхода из внутреннего цикла будет меньше чем edi и условие выхода опять не сработает.

Чтобы избежать такого "проскакивания" внутреннего цикла и нужно добавить проверку перед входом в него ("предусловие").

Comment: интересно, машина написала:
    cmp     esi, -1
    jnz
а у меня в конечном варианте:
    cmp     esi, 1
    jnz
Получается, у меня до сих пор неверно реализовано.

Comment: @kuler94, db 66h и nop выравнивают начала циклов (метки loc_4013D0, loc_4013D8) под адрес кратный 4, это дает некоторый прирост производительности. В качестве выравнивающих инструкций могут выступать "ничего не значащие" инструкции типа mov reg,reg (например mov eax,eax).

test reg,reg аналогичен сравнению регистра с 0, но в машинном коде занимает 2 байта вместо 3.

Comment: @insolor спасибо, уточню у препода об этих операциях подробнее - мне нужно разжевать как следует :)

Comment: test короче, по производительности не могу сказать. Это аналогично тому, что для обнуления регистра используется xor, хотя можно обнулять и через mov (тут выигрыш по длине инструкций даже больше: 2 байта xor eax,eax, 5 байт mov eax,0).

Comment: Еще по поводу выравнивания. Не знаю как в nasm, в fasm есть инструкция align. Вставил align 4 перед loop_i: и перед loop_j - в скомпилированном виде вместо первого align вставилось 3 нопа, вместо второго - 2.

Comment: @insolor, по поводу дополнения:
Непонятна логика именно "половинности разрядности".
А вот половину регистра cmp, скорее всего, превышал, да. Видимо, из-за этого ошибка. Но как её решила замена аргумента на единицу?

Comment: @kuler94, дополнил.

Comment: @insolor, теперь я понял.
И не рассчитывал, что кто-то тут так подробно разжует все, благодарствую :)